# How to port ImportError to Python 3 when it does not derive from BaseException

Tags: python-3.x

I am porting Mingus (2to3 did not work) manually.  Most of it is easy, simply fully qualify package and module names.  Also place brackets round `raise` arguments.

But I have hit a problem lines 30-37 of mingus\midi\pyfluidsynth.py

```
import time
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

lib = find_library('fluidsynth') or find_library('libfluidsynth')\
     or find_library('libfluidsynth-1')
if lib is None:
    raise (ImportError, "Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
```

line 37 this raises the run-time error :
`TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException`

How to port this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    from somelib import *
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
```

Comment: I've amended question to show prior lines which clash with your suggestion.  It doesn't look like a try catch pattern, instead a test for find_library() return pattern.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
lib = find_library('fluidsynth') or find_library('libfluidsynth')\
     or find_library('libfluidsynth-1')
if lib is None:
    raise ImportError( "Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
```